# Vaadin 7 CDI, inject EJB in View

Tags: cdi, vaadin7

```
@Local
public interface MediaManagerService {

@Stateless
public class MediaManagerServiceImpl implements MediaManagerService, Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3484115607954217804L;

    @PersistenceContext(name="MediaManagerPersistenceUnit", 
                        unitName="MediaManagerPersistenceUnit")
    private EntityManager _em;
```

I can inject service successful in UI by this code:

```
@CDIUI
public class MainUI extends ManagedUI {
    private Navigator _navigator;

    @Inject
    private CDIViewProvider _viewProvider;

    @Inject
    private MediaManagerService _service;
```

But in the view, it always throws null.

```
@CDIView("MovieView")
public class MovieView extends ManagedComponent implements View {
    public static final String NAME = "MovieView";

    @Inject
    private MediaManagerService _service;
```

The _service always throws null in the View.
This is from the console:

```
10:17:25,052 INFO  [com.vaadin.cdi.CDIViewProvider] (default task-5) Attempting to retrieve view name from string ""
10:17:25,052 INFO  [com.vaadin.cdi.CDIViewProvider] (default task-5) Looking for view with name ""
10:17:25,053 INFO  [com.vaadin.cdi.CDIViewProvider] (default task-5) com.tien113.ui.MovieView is annotated, the viewName is "MovieView"
10:17:25,053 INFO  [com.vaadin.cdi.CDIViewProvider] (default task-5) com.tien113.ui.LoginView is annotated, the viewName is ""
10:17:25,053 INFO  [com.vaadin.cdi.CDIViewProvider] (default task-5) Bean Managed Bean [class com.tien113.ui.LoginView] with qualifiers [@Any @Default] with viewName "" is one alternative
10:17:25,054 INFO  [com.vaadin.cdi.CDIViewProvider] (default task-5) Attempting to retrieve view with name ""
10:17:25,054 INFO  [com.vaadin.cdi.CDIViewProvider] (default task-5) Looking for view with name ""
10:17:25,054 INFO  [com.vaadin.cdi.CDIViewProvider] (default task-5) com.tien113.ui.MovieView is annotated, the viewName is "MovieView"
10:17:25,055 INFO  [com.vaadin.cdi.CDIViewProvider] (default task-5) com.tien113.ui.LoginView is annotated, the viewName is ""
10:17:25,055 INFO  [com.vaadin.cdi.CDIViewProvider] (default task-5) Bean Managed Bean [class com.tien113.ui.LoginView] with qualifiers [@Any @Default] with viewName "" is one alternative
10:17:25,055 INFO  [com.vaadin.cdi.CDIViewProvider] (default task-5) Created new creational context for current view org.jboss.weld.context.CreationalContextImpl@5182605a
10:17:25,071 INFO  [com.vaadin.cdi.CDIViewProvider] (default task-5) Returning view instance com.tien113.ui.LoginView@6713e65a
10:17:27,104 INFO  [com.vaadin.cdi.CDIViewProvider] (default task-9) Attempting to retrieve view name from string "MovieView"
10:17:27,104 INFO  [com.vaadin.cdi.CDIViewProvider] (default task-9) Looking for view with name "MovieView"
10:17:27,104 INFO  [com.vaadin.cdi.CDIViewProvider] (default task-9) com.tien113.ui.MovieView is annotated, the viewName is "MovieView"
10:17:27,104 INFO  [com.vaadin.cdi.CDIViewProvider] (default task-9) Bean Managed Bean [class com.tien113.ui.MovieView] with qualifiers [@Any @Default] with viewName "MovieView" is one alternative
10:17:27,105 INFO  [com.vaadin.cdi.CDIViewProvider] (default task-9) com.tien113.ui.LoginView is annotated, the viewName is ""
10:17:27,105 INFO  [com.vaadin.cdi.CDIViewProvider] (default task-9) Attempting to retrieve view with name "MovieView"
10:17:27,105 INFO  [com.vaadin.cdi.CDIViewProvider] (default task-9) Looking for view with name "MovieView"
10:17:27,105 INFO  [com.vaadin.cdi.CDIViewProvider] (default task-9) com.tien113.ui.MovieView is annotated, the viewName is "MovieView"
10:17:27,105 INFO  [com.vaadin.cdi.CDIViewProvider] (default task-9) Bean Managed Bean [class com.tien113.ui.MovieView] with qualifiers [@Any @Default] with viewName "MovieView" is one alternative
10:17:27,105 INFO  [com.vaadin.cdi.CDIViewProvider] (default task-9) com.tien113.ui.LoginView is annotated, the viewName is ""
10:17:27,106 INFO  [com.vaadin.cdi.CDIViewProvider] (default task-9) Releasing creational context for current view org.jboss.weld.context.CreationalContextImpl@5182605a
10:17:27,106 INFO  [com.vaadin.cdi.CDIViewProvider] (default task-9) Created new creational context for current view org.jboss.weld.context.CreationalContextImpl@5bfe6e21
10:17:27,164 SEVERE [com.vaadin.server.DefaultErrorHandler] (default task-9) : java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.tien113.ui.MovieView.genreFilterComboBox(MovieView.java:180) [classes:]
    at com.tien113.ui.MovieView.movieLayout(MovieView.java:80) [classes:]
    at com.tien113.ui.MovieView.<init>(MovieView.java:70) [classes:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20-ea]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20-ea]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20-ea]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20-ea]
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.ConstructorInjectionPoint.newInstance(ConstructorInjectionPoint.java:110) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.ConstructorInjectionPoint.invokeAroundConstructCallbacks(ConstructorInjectionPoint.java:84) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.ConstructorInjectionPoint.newInstance(ConstructorInjectionPoint.java:71) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.AbstractInstantiator.newInstance(AbstractInstantiator.java:28) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BasicInjectionTarget.produce(BasicInjectionTarget.java:85) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BeanInjectionTarget.produce(BeanInjectionTarget.java:183) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.create(ManagedBean.java:149) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at com.vaadin.cdi.internal.UIBeanStore.getBeanInstance(UIBeanStore.java:57) [vaadin-cdi-1.0.0.alpha2.jar:1.0.0.alpha2]
    at com.vaadin.cdi.internal.UIScopedContext.get(UIScopedContext.java:105) [vaadin-cdi-1.0.0.alpha2.jar:1.0.0.alpha2]
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:733) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:753) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at org.jboss.weld.util.ForwardingBeanManager.getReference(ForwardingBeanManager.java:61) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.builtin.BeanManagerProxy.getReference(BeanManagerProxy.java:80) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at com.vaadin.cdi.CDIViewProvider.getView(CDIViewProvider.java:213) [vaadin-cdi-1.0.0.alpha2.jar:1.0.0.alpha2]
    at com.vaadin.navigator.Navigator.navigateTo(Navigator.java:512) [vaadin-server-7.3.0.beta1.jar:7.3.0.beta1]
    at com.tien113.ui.LoginView.lambda$0(LoginView.java:80) [classes:]
    at com.tien113.ui.LoginView$$Lambda$2/843139639.buttonClick(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20-ea]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20-ea]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20-ea]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20-ea]
    at com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod.receiveEvent(ListenerMethod.java:508) [vaadin-server-7.3.0.beta1.jar:7.3.0.beta1]
    at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:198) [vaadin-server-7.3.0.beta1.jar:7.3.0.beta1]
    at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:161) [vaadin-server-7.3.0.beta1.jar:7.3.0.beta1]
    at com.vaadin.server.AbstractClientConnector.fireEvent(AbstractClientConnector.java:978) [vaadin-server-7.3.0.beta1.jar:7.3.0.beta1]
    at com.vaadin.ui.Button.fireClick(Button.java:393) [vaadin-server-7.3.0.beta1.jar:7.3.0.beta1]
    at com.vaadin.ui.Button$1.click(Button.java:57) [vaadin-server-7.3.0.beta1.jar:7.3.0.beta1]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20-ea]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20-ea]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20-ea]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20-ea]
    at com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager.applyInvocation(ServerRpcManager.java:168) [vaadin-server-7.3.0.beta1.jar:7.3.0.beta1]
    at com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager.applyInvocation(ServerRpcManager.java:118) [vaadin-server-7.3.0.beta1.jar:7.3.0.beta1]
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocations(ServerRpcHandler.java:281) [vaadin-server-7.3.0.beta1.jar:7.3.0.beta1]
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleRpc(ServerRpcHandler.java:174) [vaadin-server-7.3.0.beta1.jar:7.3.0.beta1]
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.UidlRequestHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UidlRequestHandler.java:93) [vaadin-server-7.3.0.beta1.jar:7.3.0.beta1]
    at com.vaadin.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:41) [vaadin-server-7.3.0.beta1.jar:7.3.0.beta1]
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1406) [vaadin-server-7.3.0.beta1.jar:7.3.0.beta1]
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:237) [vaadin-server-7.3.0.beta1.jar:7.3.0.beta1]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:130) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.websockets.jsr.JsrWebSocketFilter.doFilter(JsrWebSocketFilter.java:123) [undertow-websockets-jsr-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:113) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:56) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:240) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:227) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:73) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:146) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:177) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:727) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20-ea]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20-ea]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20-ea]
```

It threw error on the line I use _service.

Can anyone help me, please....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the stack trace you are trying to use the injected bean in the constructor (in a method called by the constructor). The bean will be injected after initialising, so it is null in the constructor. You have 2 possibilities.

1. Inject the bean in the Constructor.
2. Call this methods from a different function annotated with @PostConstruct

I'd recommend the second approach. Here you will find more about the different injection methods: http://www.byteslounge.com/tutorials/java-ee-cdi-dependency-injection-inject-tutorial

Comment: Thanks for reply. My situation is very different with your answer.

I only have problem with vaadin view when inject service into view.

I didn't have problem with CDI when inject service into UI. It works perfectly.

In addition, in normal project without vaadin, CDI works perfectly for me.

Comment: @tien113: So have you tried not using the injected service in the constructor? your constructor seems to call movieLayout on line 70, which calls genreFilterComboBox on line 80 and this method is probably using _service on line 180. Is that right?

Comment: Thanks so much. You save my life. I removed everything in constructor, put in the properly method. Everything works perfectly now.